# Google Cloud PubSub - better way to list custom attributes?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, attributes, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to simplify my Python code that publishes data to PubSub.  This works:

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import json

credentials_path = '/path/to/my/service.account.privateKey.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_path

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
# topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)         # this is the same as writing the string 'projects/{projectId}/topics/{topicId}'
topic_path = 'projects/MY_PROJECT/topics/MY_TOPIC'

data = 'Sensor data ready!'
data = data.encode('utf-8')                                     # data needs to be a bytestring
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, sensorName='garden', temperature='75.0', humidity='88.8')            # when you publish a message, the client returns a future
print(f'published message id {future.result()}')
```

But I'm hoping for a more elegant way to pass my custom attributes.  Instead of listing them one by one like this:

```
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, sensorName='garden', temperature='75.0', humidity='88.8')
```

...is there a way to do something along the lines of:

```
attributes = {
    'sensorName': 'garden',
    'temperature': '75.0',
    'humidity': '60'
}
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, attributes)
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: use `**` to unpack dictionary  `publish(..., **attributes)`

Comment: I wondering why not sent it all as JSON string in `data`

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Comment: I originally pushed the json object into 'data' with json.dumps() and json.loads(), then I realized they allowed for a custom attribute field and wanted to try that to make the code shorter and a little more legible. thanks again!

Comment: Hi Ryan, and furas, if this is answered as I understand it is; I would suggest to post it as a complete Answer so that other users from the community can benefit from it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @furas mentions above, all that's needed is to unpack the `attributes` object as it's passed in to `publish(...)`

```
attributes = {
    'sensorName': 'garden',
    'temperature': '75.0',
    'humidity': '60'
}
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data, **attributes)
```

Thanks,
Ryan